# Let $L_1$ be the language over alphabet $\{0, 1\}$ defined by $L_1 = \{x : \#_{01}(x) \bmod 3 = 0\}$. Give a regular expression that denotes $L_1$

Tags: computer-science, regular-expressions

Let $L_1$ be the language over alphabet $\{0, 1\}$ defined by $L_1 = \{x : \#_{01}(x) \bmod 3 = 0\}$.

Give a regular expression that denotes $L_1$, and justify its correctness

---

attempt

Need 010101 such that mod 3 = 0

How would I make a regex for this?

$R_1 = (01)^*$. How would I do the mod condition?

Comment: I would think for example, 100111010001 would also qualify as being in $L_1$.

Comment: Actually yeah that makes more sense

Comment: $L_1$ consists of those strings $x$ such that the number of symbols in it is a multiple of $3$. So you need to first represent three symbols by a regular expression and then have a provision to repeat them any number of times.

Comment: $0^*(010101)^*1^*$ would work right?

Comment: No. This would include $0$.

Comment: this would right? $0^*(00^*11^*00^*11^*00^*11^*)^*1^*$

Comment: That includes $01$, but it shouldn't.

Comment: I thought it must have $010101$?

Comment: The operator $*$ allows the possibility of no occurences of its argument. The term $(00^∗11^∗00^∗11^∗00^∗11^∗)^∗$ means that $(00^∗11^∗00^∗11^∗00^∗11^∗)$ could occur zero times.

Comment: You edited your comment, but it must have $010101$ but it cannot have $01$.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Hmm... would $(1^*00^∗11^∗00^∗11^∗00^∗11^∗0^*)^*$ make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85568/discussion-between-joey-kilpatrick-and-tree-garen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our regular expression must include every string that has a multiple of $3$ occurences of the string $(01)$. This includes $$
(01)(01)(01)\\
10(01)(01)(01)10\\
1100(01)1100(01)1100(01)1100\\
10(01)(01)(01)(01)(01)(01)10\\
1()00
$$
Notice that we can regroup some of the above expressions as$$
(01)(01)(01)\\
1(001)(01)(011)0\\
11(000111)(000111)(000111)00\\
1(001)(01)(01)(01)(01)(011)0\\
1()00
$$

so that each set of parentheses includes as many $0$'s as it can on the left and as many  $1$'s as it can on the right. We will denote $aa^*$ as $a^+$. We can rewrite the strings as $$
(0^+1^+)(0^+1^+)(0^+1^+)\\
1(0^+1^+)(0^+1^+)(0^+1^+)0\\
11(0^+1^+)(0^+1^+)(0^+1^+)00\\
1(0^+1^+)(0^+1^+)(0^+1^+)(0^+1^+)(0^+1^+)(0^+1^+)0\\
1()00
$$

The regular expression that captures exactly these strings is $$
1^*((0^+1^+)(0^+1^+)(0^+1^+))^*0^* \\
= 1^*(((0^+1^+)^3)^*)0^*
$$